# Highlighting row and column of corresponding element of each table on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, hover

I have two tables side by side with each other as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

When I hover over an element on any table, I want the corresponding element on the other table to be highlighted as well (i.e. if I hover over element with index [0,0] on one table, I want the corresponding element with index [0,0] on the other table to be highlighted as well).

I've used the suggestion here http://jsfiddle.net/rhyu3r0r/ to perform this action on one table (however, instead of toggleClass, I used addClass and removeClass). How would I go about doing the above action?

Comment: where is the other table

Comment: Well in the outer table, I have two inner tables, those are the tables I am speaking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way of doing it, would be a lot easier if the tables had id's but this works too:

```
$('table table td').hover(function() {
    $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('hovered');
    //which cell is selected
    cell = $this.closest("table").find("td").index(this);
   $this.closest("table").parent().siblings("td").find("td").eq(cell).toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhyu3r0r/1/

Comment: some optimisation could be considered to make it a bit faster but you get the idea.. you could also read the row index and cell index separate and use that if you choose
but most importanlty STOP using tables for layout. :)